# Identifying Visitor's using Proxy

Tags: web-application, proxy, monitoring

I want to detect my website visitor's using any duplicate proxies ?

If so how to avoid them? also how to identify the proxy is an HTTP proxy or a SOCKS proxy ?

Comment: Can you clarify your question more? Are you looking to identify users and distinguish between them based on their IPs and other session paramenters?

Comment: ya , i think somebody stealing my website details

Answer (score 1):

If [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header is enable you can use it.

> The X-Forwarded-For (XFF) HTTP header field is a de facto standard for identifying the originating IP address of a client connecting to a web server through an HTTP proxy or load balancer. This is an HTTP request header which was introduced by the Squid caching proxy server's developers. An effort has been started at IETF for standardizing the Forwarded HTTP header.

---

Also you can use to [Evercookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evercookie) for monitoring your users IP/activities.

> Evercookie is a JavaScript-based application created by Samy Kamkar which produces zombie cookies in a web browser that are intentionally difficult to delete.